# Approximation of a holomorphic function vanishing at a submanifold by polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-manifolds

Suppose $M$ is a complex [*affine algebraic manifold*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_manifold) in ${\mathbb C}^n$ (I mean, a set of common zeroes of a system of polynomials on ${\mathbb C}^n$, which is at the same time a smooth manifold). Consider the space ${\mathcal O}({\mathbb C}^n)$ of all holomoprphic functions on ${\mathbb C}^n$ with the usual topology of uniform convergence on compact sets. Alexei Pirkovskii in his paper [Arens–Michael envelopes...](https://www.ams.org/journals/mosc/2008-69-00/S0077-1554-08-00169-6/S0077-1554-08-00169-6.pdf) (page 42, example 3.6) shows that

> If a function $f\in {\mathcal O}({\mathbb C}^n)$ vanishes on $M$,
> $$
> f\Big|_M=0,
> $$
> then it can be approximated in ${\mathcal O}({\mathbb C}^n)$ by a sequence of polynomials $g_i\in {\mathbb C}[x_1,...,x_n])$ which also vanish on $M$:
> $$
> g_i\Big|_M=0,\qquad g_i\overset{{\mathcal O}({\mathbb C}^n)}{\underset{i\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}}f
> $$

Pirkovskii uses Cartan's theorems for this, but I have a feeling that this is too complicated. Is it possible that there is a more or less simple way to prove this, without Cartan?

Comment: An observation: Let $I$ be the ideal in $\mathcal O(\mathbb C^n)$ consisting of all $f$ such that $f|_{M}=0$. The statement seems to follow from (maybe to be equivalent to) the assertion that $I$ is generated by polynomials.

Comment: Tom, excuse me, what is meant by "generated by polynomials"?

Comment: I meant that, as an ideal in the ring of global holomorphic functions, $I$ is generated by elements of $I$ that belong to the subring consisting of polynomials. I would guess that this is true, and it would imply your statement.

Comment: Tom, 
$$
\forall f\in I\quad \exists p_1,...,p_k\in{\mathbb C}[x_1,...,x_n] \quad p_i\Big|_M=0\quad \&\quad  \exists h_1,...,h_k\in{\mathcal O}(M)\quad f=\sum_{i=1}^k p_i\cdot h_i
$$
-- if this is your point, then of course this implies what I need. But why is this true?

Comment: I don't know whether it is true, but I am guessing that it is true.